# Simulate click javascript to element by class

Tags: javascript, c#, getelementsbyclassname

I am using execelementasync in c#.

I want to use JavaScript too simulate a click to this button:

```
<a class="btn confirm" href="#">
  <h5>
    Begin
  </h5>
</a>
```

**My code:**

```
string jsScriptB = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(@"<js><![CDATA[ document.getElementByClassName('btn confirm').click();]]></js>").Value;
            browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsScriptB);
```

I am really not sure what is going wrong but the button does not click.

**Question:** How can I click that button using JavaScript

Comment: Winform web browser control ?

Comment: @Adrian sort of it is the chromium cefsharp browser in a windows form

Comment: it could be that you haven't checked to see if DOM is ready. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t

Comment: @grepLines I'm not sure that's the case. Other code (like  document.all(""username"").value = ""testSlash3"";) works, but this code doesn't

Comment: can you do a `console.log(document.getElementByClassName('btn confirm'))` ?

Comment: @grepLines  I have an answer now, it was a silly typo on my part. Anyway, thank you for helping and have a nice night!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript document.getElementsByClassName will return a array of HtmlElement so you can't call click on it directly. you need to click on a single element

document.getElementsByClassName('btn confirm')[0].click();

Secondly you are trying to use 2 class in your getElementByClassName which is invalid in first place.

You can better call it like

```
document.querySelectorAll('.btn,.confirm')
```

or just call querySelector if there is only one element in your html document. later you can call it like

```
browser.Document.GetElementById(".btn,.confirm").InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: thank you, that solves it. I had tried adding [0] based on a similar question but foolishly made a typo and said document.getElementByClassName('btn confirm')[0].click(); (element, not elements). Anyway, thank you!